# How to print a remotely generated file on a local printer through the web browser, using python?

Tags: python, windows, networking, browser, printing

### Overview

- We are using a database system hosted remotely.
- Said database system allows us to run our own chunks of python code to access and use the data on the dbms. python scripts are defined and pasted in to a box which are then run on a button press in the web app.
- We have a printer that can only be accessed through the local network.
- We don't have our own server
- we need to print a file generated by some python code running on the dbms.

I have all of the code to generate the file (text file), however printing it is my issue. I previously tried using FTP to print, and this works but only on the LAN. Because the dbms is remote, any scripts running there cannot access the printer. We are not able to port forward the printer either, since we do not have access to those controls.

So, I was thinking I could use the browser to print the file, since the browser has access to the dbms (it is running in a webapp) and the user's local printers.

We connect to the server over https through a browser.

An extra issue is that this must be accomplished in python, because that is the only customisation I have access to for the dbms.

I have explored using os.startfile("file path", "print"), however this doesn't work as the it is an unknown file extension (.zpl). I also feel as though this would not work because it would be executed on whatever is running the dbms and not on the local users machine.

Currently all machines that would need to use this are running windows, however I would like to be able to make this cross-platform between windows, linux, mac and probably android also. But I can cross that bridge when I get to it.

I am aware that this may not be possible or maybe I'm trying to solve it in a dumb way.

Any tips or ideas would be useful!

Comment: browsers don't run python, they run javascript, the "print" code has to be written in javascript ... see [print.js](https://printjs.crabbly.com/), things that look like it's running python in browser is either running it on the server and sending results back or running a javascript implementation of python.

Comment: you haven't said anything about how you run the code chunks or how you access the server ? are you connecting through SSH ? or is the server running an HTTP server that your browsers connect on ? add as much details as you can to get a good answer.

Comment: Just to be clear, the dbms generates the zpl code through some python script and you can receive that zpl code in your web app by accessing the dbms via an api or something.
And you want to send that zpl from the browser to a printer in the clients local network? That could be tricky